# Solr nested documents : Query for child documents filtered by a parent field

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solr-query-syntax

I have following parent-child models

parent:

```java
public class DataSet {
    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type="type_dataset";
    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private String dataSourceId;

    @Field
    private String serviceId;

    @Field(child=true)
    private List<DataSetColumn> columns;
}
```

child:

```java
 public class DataSetColumn {
        @Field
        private String id;
        @Field
        private String name;
        @Field
        private String type="type_column";  
    }
```

I can query for parent documents filtered by fields belonging to the parent as:

```
http://solrserver:8886/solr/BeanTest10/select?q=*:*&fq=(type:type_dataset)&fl=*,[child
parentFilter=type:type_dataset]&wt=json&indent=true
```

Now I want to:

1. Query for "DataSetColumns"(child documents) filtered by serviceId (parent field)
2. also return "dataSourceId" which is a field in parent in the response (DataSet)

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: so, you want to return child documents, right and search in child documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could achieve something like this wit the power of [BlockJoinParentQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/other-parsers.html#block-join-parent-query-parser).

Basic syntax is the following - `q={!parent which=<allParents>}<someChildren>`

In your case it could be transformed to something like - `+{!parent which="type:type_dataset"}name:random* +service_id:1`

The trick to return child documents will be the same ([child doc transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/transforming-result-documents.html#child-childdoctransformerfactory)):

```
fl=data_id,[child parentFilter=type:type_dataset]
```

If needed you could limit child fields as well via `fl` construction.